# Regex to validate range of numbers from 50 to 1000 with step of 50

Tags: php, regex

I got stuck with regex that could validate a number from 50 to 1000 with step of 50.

Could anyone please help to figure this out?

Comment: Please post the regex you tried alongside the string. What it matches and what it should match.

Comment: Use instead 

    `in_array($value, range(50, 1000, 50));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use regex? That will only make it complex

Use an array of the range and in_array.

```
$range = range(50,1000,50);

$input = 34;   
var_dump(in_array($input, $range)); // false


$input = 150;
var_dump(in_array($input, $range));//true
```

https://3v4l.org/3ToT9

---

The regex version is this:

Either a tree digit number that ends with `50` or `00` or exactly 1000

```
$input = 950;

var_dump(preg_match("/\b\d{0,1}[5|0]0\b|\b1000\b/", $input));
```

Answer (score 0):

Andreas's regex matches `050`, `2|0`, `9|0` and `000`, but does not match `50`. Also `{1}` serves no purpose in the pattern. The pipe in the character class is flatly incorrect.

Here is a correct pattern that prohibits a leading zero on `50`...

Code:

```
preg_match('/^(?:100|5|[1-9][05])0$/', $string)
```

This pattern matches the full string because of the start `^` and end `$` of string anchors.

It effectively matches:

1. `1000` or
2. `50` or
3. any 3-digit number that ends in `00` or `50`

In all qualifying cases, the number is at least 2 digits long and ends with a zero.